# Вывод без дубликатов в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день! 
Есть у меня 2 таблицы.

User

```
--------------
|id|  name   |
--------------
|1 | Shynaz  |
--------------
|2 | Olzhas  |
--------------
|3 | Zhandos |
--------------
|4 | Erasyl  |
--------------
|5 | Miras   |
--------------
```

и вторая таблица client_contacts

```
-------------------------------------
|id| type |     number    | user_id |
-------------------------------------
|1 |   1  |  +77075169845 |    1    |
-------------------------------------
|2 |   1  |  +77756591236 |    2    |
-------------------------------------
|3 |   1  |  +77059637825 |    3    |
-------------------------------------
|4 |   2  |    2986931    |    3    |
-------------------------------------
|5 |   2  |    3896514    |    4    |
-------------------------------------
|6 |   3  | some@gmail.com|    5    |
-------------------------------------
```

И мой запрос:

```
Select u.name, cc.number from user u
    Left Join client_contacts cc
    On u.id = cc.user_id
```

Проблема в том что он дублирует юзеров в выводе(1 User может содержать несколько контактов). Мне нужно чтобы выводился `user` и согласно его `id` выводился `number` без дублирования `user`.

Comment: а что делать с user=3 у которого 2 номера? как их выводить?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, нужно выводить 1 номер для каждого юзера или `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте

```
SELECT u.name, MAX(cc.number)
FROM user u
LEFT Join client_contacts cc
  ON u.id = cc.user_id
GROUP BY u.name
```

так как вам нету разницы какую из номеров брать. А так есть еще один метод. Склеить эти строки.

```
SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(cc.number SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM user u
LEFT Join client_contacts cc
  ON u.id = cc.user_id
GROUP BY u.name
```

Comment: A что будет когда `cc.number` будет `email`?

Comment: ничего страшного не будет, это операция склеивание строк. он просто склеит `email` тоже

Comment: Hет в первом примере?

Comment: так как  поле имеет тип строка, ей нету разницы это телефон или email. он просто будет брать первую строку, сортированную по алфавитному порядку. если номер он выше, если буква ниже. получается запрос даст номер. если нету номера, даст email

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT нет в T-SQL. для SQL Server можно так: `select u.id, u.name, (SELECT c.num + '; ' FROM contacts c WHERE c.userId = u.id FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
from user u join contacts c on u.id = c.userId`

Comment: @Saidolim _"Где тут сказано что нужен Transact-SQL?"_ -- у вопроса есть тег sql-server = Microsoft SQL Server, см. [SQL Shared Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198336.aspx) - Transact-SQL (T-SQL).

Comment: @Stack вроде вы правы. сорри. Удаляю свой коммент. Спасибо за заметку

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то речь идет об объединение строк и вывода номеров телефонов через запятую. Для mysql группировку можно выполниться с помощью *GROUP_CONCATE* и *GROUP BY*.

```
Select `u`.`name`, GROUP_CONCATE(`cc`.`number` SEPARATOR ', ') from `user` as `u`
Left Join `client_contacts` as `cc`
On `u`.`id` = `cc`.`user_id` 
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Для SQL Server подобного простого решения похоже нет. Как эмулировать group_concat на SQL Server хорошо описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server). Я не специалист по SQL Server и воздержусь от приведения примера конкретно для SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `DISTINCT` - применяется внутри некоторых агригатных функций.
Например:

`COUNT(name)` - кол-во записей, где name не NULL

`COUNT(DISTINCT name)` - кол-во записей с разными name не равными NULL

```
Select u.name, cc.number, DISTINCT u.id from user u
    Left Join client_contacts cc
    On u.id = cc.user_id
```

Comment: думаю, `DISTINCT` тут не поможет, так как у него в `userId=3` есть 2 номера. `+77059637825` и `2986931`

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev, Не все учел исправил.